# Alert Conditions for HH, LH, LL, HL

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

My indicator prints the labels with Higher High, Lower High, Lower Low and Higher Low in the graph. I am trying to add alert condtions for the same but i am getting error that "Index 0 is out of bounds, array size is 0".

Could anyone tell me the correct alert conditions for HH, LH, LL and HL please. Thank you.

```
//@version=5
indicator('Testing', overlay=true)
prd1 = input.int(defval=30, title='ZigZag Period', minval=2)
upcol1 = color.lime
dncol1 = color.red
txtcol = color.black
zz1width = 1

float ph1 = ta.highestbars(high, prd1) == 0 ? high : na
float pl1 = ta.lowestbars(low, prd1) == 0 ? low : na

var dir1 = 0
iff_1 = pl1 and na(ph1) ? -1 : dir1
dir1 := ph1 and na(pl1) ? 1 : iff_1

var max_array_size = 10  // [5, 2] matrix
var zigzag1 = array.new_float(0)
oldzigzag1 = array.copy(zigzag1)

add_to_zigzag(pointer, value, bindex) =>
    array.unshift(pointer, bindex)
    array.unshift(pointer, value)
    if array.size(pointer) > max_array_size
        array.pop(pointer)
        array.pop(pointer)

update_zigzag(pointer, value, bindex, dir) =>
    if array.size(pointer) == 0
        add_to_zigzag(pointer, value, bindex)
    else
        if dir == 1 and value > array.get(pointer, 0) or dir == -1 and value < array.get(pointer, 0)
            array.set(pointer, 0, value)
            array.set(pointer, 1, bindex)
        0.

dir1changed = ta.change(dir1)
if ph1 or pl1
    if dir1changed
        add_to_zigzag(zigzag1, dir1 == 1 ? ph1 : pl1, bar_index)
    else
        update_zigzag(zigzag1, dir1 == 1 ? ph1 : pl1, bar_index, dir1)

if array.size(zigzag1) >= 6
    var line zzline1 = na
    var label zzlabel1 = na
    if array.get(zigzag1, 0) != array.get(oldzigzag1, 0) or array.get(zigzag1, 1) != array.get(oldzigzag1, 1)
        if array.get(zigzag1, 2) == array.get(oldzigzag1, 2) and array.get(zigzag1, 3) == array.get(oldzigzag1, 3)
            line.delete(zzline1)
            label.delete(zzlabel1)
        zzline1 := line.new(x1=math.round(array.get(zigzag1, 1)), y1=array.get(zigzag1, 0), x2=math.round(array.get(zigzag1, 3)), y2=array.get(zigzag1, 2), color=dir1 == 1 ? upcol1 : dncol1, width=zz1width)
        zzline1
        hhlltxt = dir1 == 1 ? array.get(zigzag1, 0) > array.get(zigzag1, 4) ? 'HH' : 'LH' : array.get(zigzag1, 0) < array.get(zigzag1, 4) ? 'LL' : 'HL'
        labelcol = dir1 == 1 ? array.get(zigzag1, 0) > array.get(zigzag1, 4) ? upcol1 : dncol1 : array.get(zigzag1, 0) < array.get(zigzag1, 4) ? dncol1 : upcol1
        zzlabel1 := label.new(x=math.round(array.get(zigzag1, 1)), y=array.get(zigzag1, 0), text=hhlltxt, color=labelcol, textcolor=txtcol, style=dir1 == 1 ? label.style_label_down : label.style_label_up)
        zzlabel1


alertcondition( dir1 == 1 and array.get(zigzag1, 0) > array.get(zigzag1, 4), title='HH', message='HH')
alertcondition( dir1 == 1 and array.get(zigzag1, 0) < array.get(zigzag1, 4), title='HL', message='HL')
alertcondition( dir1 != 1 and array.get(zigzag1, 0) < array.get(zigzag1, 4), title='LL', message='LL')
alertcondition( dir1 != 1 and array.get(zigzag1, 0) > array.get(zigzag1, 4), title='LH', message='LH')
```

Comment: Don't bother. This is a repainting indicator. Your alerts will not work properly.

Comment: I know it repaints but it will help me, When the alerts stop i will know it reached the HH or LL. Could you tell me the correct alertconditions please.

Comment: Why don't you use `alert()` instead of `alertcondition()`?

Comment: I can use alert() also, Could you help me please...

Answer (score 0):

You just need an `alert()` right after you create your pivot label.

```
    alert_txt = "Alert:\n" + hhlltxt
    label.new(bar_index, high, alert_txt, color=color.blue, textcolor=color.white)
    alert(alert_txt, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

I have added another `label` for you to show where you would get your alerts.

[image]

As you can see, there you will get many alerts until you establish just two pivot points. You will even get different types of alerts (e.g. LH, HH) in between.

Comment: Thanks Vitruvius iam getting all the alerts now but i dont have control of which alerts to fire.. What if i only need HH or LL alert to fire. I appriciate your help if you could create alertconditions please it will also help me to test in a strategy. Thanks a lot Vitruvius.